# How to store ArrayList of Maps in Google App Engine objectify (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to store arraylist with raw type hashmap in datastore. Please any one help me.

Comment: Could you give some example of what you want to store and what you have tried. Collections are actually stored as embedded entities and hence will probably not play nice with maps which have their own embed hacks applied to them. However, if you list your data requirement we can probably help you refactor to not need a List of Hashmaps.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [Serialize Annotation](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Serializing) which will flatten your data structure but this has some limits for example, the serialized data must be less than 1MB and all objectify annotations such as transient are ignored.

```
@Entity
class EntityWithSerialized {
    @Id Long id;
    @Serialize List<Map<Object, Object>> stuff;
}

//...
EntityWithSerialized entity = new EntityWithSerialized(12345,listMapObject);
ofy().save().entity(entity).now();
ofy().load().key(12345).now();
```

Comment: Thank you Usman Ismail. But it stores <Blob: 1000 bytes> only.., How can i retrieve actual value from Datastore?

Comment: It stores the entire data, up to 1MB. Why do you say it stores the first 1000 bytes?

Comment: Am also stored this way..., but my entity field have a <Blob: 1000 bytes> this value only.., i can not see original text.., @Serialize its only enough or doing something else like any serialization process?